Are there any Torah sources for raising children with a close relationship to grandparents?
I teach a class on chinuch habanim and would like to address this topic. Although I know there is tremendous value in general to children having a relationship with grandparents, I couldn't seem to find anything about it in Torah sources.

There’s the Gemara that says that grandparents are like parents to the kids (which implies they’re very close with them)

והודעתם לבניך ולבני בניך

See Yalkut Yosef, Kibbud Av Va'em, vol. 2, p. 496. this about respecting grandparents

זכור ימות עולם בינו שנות דור ודור שאל אביך ויגדך זקניך ויאמרו לך.

It’s noteworthy that Yaakov goes out of his way to call Avraham his father in Vayishlach 32:10 unlike how he later says ״אבותי״ “וַיֹּ֘אמֶר֮ and instead says: יַעֲקֹב֒ אֱלֹהֵי֙ אָבִ֣י אַבְרָהָ֔ם וֵאלֹהֵ֖י אָבִ֣י יִצְחָ֑ק יְהֹוָ֞ה הָאֹמֵ֣ר אֵלַ֗י שׁ֧וּב לְאַרְצְךָ֛ וּלְמוֹלַדְתְּךָ֖ וְאֵיטִ֥יבָה עִמָּֽךְ׃”

@RebHarvey:  Yes, and Hashem Himself says to Yaakov "Avraham your father" in Genesis 28:13

@J.W.Tanner yes, and interestingly there, only Avraham is referred to as father, and not Yitzchak.

See also Rashi on on Shemot 18:2   https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Exodus.18.1.2?lang=bi

There's a lot to say about the relationship to Torah that a grandfather has to his grandchild...
A grandfather is obligated to play a role in educating his grandson in Torah study. The Gemara in Kiddushin 30a relates how the grandfather of Zevulun ben Dan took pains to teach him halacha, gemara, mishnah, chumash and aggada. Such action is no small feat, and clearly underlines the importance attributed to a grandfather’s position in chinuch. Whilst learning in such depth with one’s grandson is perhaps harder to accomplish these days, every grandfather must endeavour to maintain an avid interest in their grandson’s talmud torah. This obligation is famously derived from the words:

"והודעתם לבניך ולבני בניך"
“You shall make them known to your sons and your grandsons” - Devarim 4:9.

Indeed, such is this commitment to teaching Torah to one’s grandson, that chazal view it upon doing so, as if he had personally received the Torah from Har Sinai.1
This idea is illustrated beautifully by the following story related in the Yerushalmi Shabbos 1:2. Rabbi Yehoshua ben Levi had the practise to review everything that his grandson had learnt with him every erev Shabbos. One week he forgot his usual undertaking, and instead made his way to the bathhouse in preparation for the coming Shabbos. Upon his arrival he realised his mistake, and instead of washing, quickly clothed himself and returned to learn with his grandson. His student Rav Chiya, witnessed the turn of events and questioned his Rebbi’s actions. Previously they had learnt that if a person were to go to the bathhouse and undress, and then remembers that they have not yet davened, one does not need to don his clothes again. Rather one may bathe first and can then go to daven. If this is so, why did Rabbi Yehoshua ben Levi feel the need to swiftly return to his grandson without having first bathed himself? Rabbi Yehoshua ben Levi duly responded that listening to the words of Torah from his grandson is like hearing it directly from Har Sinai.
Rabbi Boruch Ber Lebowitz זצ"ל sums up in a most clear-cut and succinct fashion. He notes authoritatively:

"שהחיוב הוא על כל איש ואיש מישראל לראות שבנו ובן בנו יהיו לתלמידי חכמים וגאונים בתורה שנאמר ושננתם לבניך"
“There is an obligation on each and every Jew to see that his son and his grandson become great Torah scholars as it says ‘And you shall teach it to your children’”.2

One cannot maintain a nonchalant approach to their children and grandchildren’s spiritual development. It is a task that lies with both a father and grandfather to ensure that their progeny are receiving a suitable and effective Torah education. Through the correct schooling and choice of yeshiva, a child will begin to start realising their potential. This overarching obligation must remain at the forefront of one’s priority, and must not be compromised. In fact, such is this responsibility, that some poskim mention that even the grandfather must help to fund a child’s tuition fees.3

1 Kiddushin 30a writes, "אמר רבי יהושע בן לוי כל המלמד את בן בנו תורה מעלה עליו הכתוב כאילו קבלה מהר סיני" – “R’ Yehoshu ben Levi said: Anyone who teaches his grandson Torah it is as if he had personally received [the Torah] from Mount Sinai”. The גמרא goes on to relate two stories of Amoraim who embodied this commitment to furthering the Torah knowledge of their grandsons.
2 See תשובה לרב אחד באשכנז בדין מצוות לימוד התורה  – ברכת שמואל, קידושין, סימן כז
3 Shach, YD 245:1. Also note Shu"t Rabbi Akiva Eiger, Siman 42 - 'ברכת להכניסו ביתום'. R’ Akiva Eiger notes down in the name of the Kessef Mishnah the following:

"ועיין בכ"מ הל' ת"ת (פ"א, ה"ב) דמחויב אפילו לשכור מלמד ללמוד עם בן, וא"כ להכניסו שייך יותר על אבי האב"
“And over there in the Kesef Mishna Hilchos Talmud Torah (1:2) [it states] that one is obligated even to hire a teacher to learn with the son, and if so, how much more so is it fitting that the grandfather enter into this obligation”.


I appreciate the content in all the responses.

I checked up the rashi in Shmos 18:2 that steve nachman referred to and I see that it discusses Tziporah being sent back to Yisro's home in Midyan. How would that apply to this question?

Also, the main theme I see running through all these responses is that grandparents should have a relationship with grandchildren. The reason would seem to be primarily that they have an obligation in chinuch/ruchniyus of grandchildren.

However, are there any sources that state why it's good for the grandchildren to have the relationship?

@morah you would have to ask stevenachman as far as you first question. You are correct with regard to your second point. As far as the final query one can argue that this need to maintain an interest in their ruchniyus is enough of a reason as to why it is good for them to have a relationship?
